# How to insert data like XXXX/XX/XX into table field?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store data like this `2013/10/07,101003,08,04,13,22,25,20,29` to mysql database , my table description is below

```
date char(10)
index char(6)
n1 char(2)
n2 char(2)
n3 char(2)
n4 char(2)
n5 char(2)
n6 char(2)
n7 char(2)
```

but when I insert `2013/10/07` to date field , the context shows in table become some number such as this `91.09090909` but not `2013/10/07` . But I set the type to `char(10)` it should store to string type

And some number with prefix 0 such as `04` was stored as `4` , how to solve this problem?

the `History.txt` store information like this

```
2004/02/10,093020,43,33,31,01,20,21,02
2004/02/05,093010,25,08,19,35,23,20,15
2004/02/01,093001,30,05,21,41,09,33,35
```

here is my code

```
<?php

    $History_Data = fopen("History.txt","r");
    $Link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","happy","l") or die ("Can't connect database\n");

    while(feof($History_Data) != 1)
    {
        $Line = fgets($History_Data);
        $Line = trim($Line,"\n");
        $Separated = preg_split("/[,]/",$Line);
        $Status = mysqli_query($Link,"Insert into history_data values ($Separated[0],$Separated[1],$Separated[2],$Separated[3],$Separated[4],$Separated[5],$Separated[6],$Separated[7],$Separated[8]);");
        echo $Status;
    }
    fclose($History_Data);

    ?>
```

thanks

Comment: You do realise that MySql has a variety of datatypes - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-overview.html - one is `DATETIME` that is more appropriate. Perhaps INTS wouldn't go a miss.

Comment: Use the proper data type for each of your fields not only it will be better but will allow a lot more flexibility within your data for instance searches and other functionality MySQL has to offer.

Comment: @EdHeal I know there is a DATETIME type,but the format is not as same as the txt file I get,So I want to store as text directly.

Comment: @user2131116, then convert it. Date in format like yours is useless because you cannot filter by it, compare it, sort by it.

Comment: @user2131116 looks fine for me http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f6c5/7 keep in mind you can format the date to anything you like when you select the it from the data by simple using the [**`data_format`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function from MYSQL

Comment: @user2131116 - See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date to convert a string to a date in mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap that date in single quotes. Without quotes it's interpreted as a mathematical expression (2013 / 10 / 07 = xx.xxxx).

```
$Status = mysqli_query($Link,"Insert into history_data values ('$Separated[0]',$Separated[1],$Separated[2],$Separated[3],$Separated[4],$Separated[5],$Separated[6],$Separated[7],$Separated[8]);");
```

But that's still wrong. You should use correct mysql data types and for date it's DATETIME. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html